# How to assign a variable in a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following method:

```
 public boolean isMatch(List<T> sources, String captured) {
      boolean isMatch = false;
      return isMatch;
 }
```

I need to start a new thread inside it like below:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            VERIFY();
        }
    };
    Thread s = new Thread(r);
    s.start();
```

The thread is supposed to perform some operations. When it finishes, I need to assign the return boolean value to the `isMatch` variable. How do I do this?

Comment: how are you planning on calling the method, how (and when) is the caller to be informed about the outcome?

Comment: since `isMatch` is a _local_ variable no code can't change it from the outside. Besides that, wouldn't the `isMatch(...)` method need to calculate the value based on the parameters anyway?

Comment: @luk2302 the method is called in a different method and the boolean result is required

Comment: why use a new thread?

Comment: If you want to wait for thread to complete then please use callable instead of runnable. Runnable cannot return value but callable interface can return value.

Comment: @Thomas the parameters at this point are ignored. All that is required is that once we get into the method, we run the Verify method and based on the return value, we return it in the isMatch method

Comment: @luk2302 i need to use a new thread because the operations being done with the VERIFY method will block the UI

Comment: @Mahesh let me look this up. Thanks

Comment: then you need to drop the return value and use a callback instead.

Comment: @luk2302 how would I do that

Comment: I'd see 2 possibilities: use a future and periodically check it or pass some function/object that can be called to put the value somewhere.

Comment: What UI library are you using?

Comment: @Priyresh this is in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need a return value, you should use the interface [`Callable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of `Runnable`. Look at what the docs say:

> The Callable interface is similar to Runnable, in that both are
>   designed for classes whose instances are potentially executed by
>   another thread. A Runnable, however, does not return a result and
>   cannot throw a checked exception.

Note that a `Callable` is submitted through an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: Thanks. Let me look into this

Comment: You are welcome! If this answers your question, please mark this answer as accepted.